# Can I add a border to node labels?

Tags: label, nodes, stroke, cytoscape

I am using the STRING app in Cytoscape and find most node labels difficult to read. I want to have white text with a black border/ stroke so that it will stand out against the white background and the color nodes, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there a way to add labels with white text and a black border? 'STRING style labels' are black with white borders, but are too small and seem to not be customizable.

Answer (score 0):

The STRING style labels actually are customizable, but they use the enhancedGraphics plugin, so the information is stored in a column -- stringdb::enhancedLabel Passthrough.  If you look in that column, you'll see how the defaults are set, but you can certainly change those defaults, for example, by changing the "labelsize" from 12 to 16.  You can similarly change the font color, outline color, etc.

-- scooter